# Conditional replace values in a column

Tags: r

I am trying to replace some key numbers with their respective people names.
Despite my two attempts, I cannot change the numbers (characters) into names, any suggestions?

Here is what I tried so far:

```
setDT(df)[person == "447745939698" , person := "John"]
```

and

```
df <-  df %>% mutate(person=ifelse(person=="447745939698","John",person))
```

Dataset:

```
structure(list(person = c("Pavel", "Anna", "Julian", "Bernardo", 
"Bryony", "KJ", "Filippo", "Duncan", "‪447761633878‬", "Josh", 
"Alex", "Berna", "Melina", "Martha", "‪447999592975‬", "‪48512044757‬", 
"Don", "‪447404192025‬", "Sofia", "Jonas", "Chantal", "‪447441458269‬", 
"‪447745939698‬", "Sungjoo", "‪447850449670‬", "Blanche", 
"Vedo", "‪966554857666‬", "‪447787327724‬", "‪447407102816‬", 
"‪447972826119‬", "‪447516428644‬", "‪447973747720‬", 
"‪447383865362‬", "‪447478422564‬", "‪447543834973‬", 
"Cris", "‪31642688469‬", "‪447921148041‬", "‪447865832098‬", 
"Steve", "‪447492829467‬", "Andrea", "‪447878829919‬", 
"‪447880747575‬", "‪34635960936‬", "‪447464871555‬", 
"‪31640838890‬", "‪46707218515‬", "‪4528822826‬", 
"‪393480848355‬", "‪447568552037‬", "‪4580211317‬", 
"‪551198299‑2336‬", "‪447935988040‬", "‪447340827646‬"
)), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-56L), index = structure(integer(0), "`__person`" = c(11L, 
43L, 2L, 12L, 4L, 26L, 5L, 21L, 37L, 17L, 8L, 7L, 20L, 10L, 3L, 
6L, 14L, 13L, 1L, 19L, 41L, 24L, 27L, 48L, 38L, 46L, 51L, 56L, 
40L, 34L, 30L, 18L, 47L, 35L, 22L, 42L, 32L, 36L, 52L, 23L, 9L, 
29L, 44L, 45L, 25L, 39L, 55L, 31L, 33L, 15L, 50L, 53L, 49L, 16L, 
54L, 28L)))
```

Comment: I get `df[person == "John"]#
   person
1:   John` afterr the replacement

Comment: `.internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x7fd6c98062e0>,`should be removed from data

Comment: Your data has unicode or some other embedded strings. For instance, when I copy the quoted string of the first number-looking element from your data, it *looks* like `‪"447761633878‬"` but on the console presents as `" 447761633878 "` (surrounding spaces). With that, you will not make the matches you expect. Look at how you are acquiring your data and see where this might be remedied (before this point).

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue mentioned with dput

Comment: Details on @ChrisRuehlemann's comment: you can't remove it from your *data*, it should be removed from the output of `dput` before placing it in SO questions. The reason is that we cannot just paste the output of that `structure` into our console and get it to work, it'll complain. (It's just to make it easier for us. It's always about us :-)

Comment: That's what I meant

Comment: Chris, yes, but I don't think that everybody else does, I thought I'd expand on it. Not a criticism on your comment at all.

Comment: @Amleto I can't find any `John` in your `dput`. Nor is there `447745939698`or `*447745939698`. Is `setDT(df)[person == "447745939698" , person := "John"]`just an illustrative example?

Comment: I have no idea why after using the structure reported above 447745939698 becomes *447745939698,  - anyway, it's in there yes. I want to change that number to John (that is why John is not in there).

Comment: Amleto, if I first correct for all of the added (hidden) spaces with `df[,person := trimws(person)]` and then do `df[person == "447745939698", person := "John"]`, it works as you ask. If you don't want to do the `trimws` stage, one could use `grepl` for this, though it is not without consequence: `df[grepl("^\\s*447745939698\\s$", person), person := "John"]` or similar.